# Multiple directives with same event binding on element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives with the same name from two separate modules. 
One is a third party module and I can't make a change to it.  It binds a mousewheel event to the element.

I wrote my own directive which is trying to undo this binding.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('ngViewport', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: -1,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                return true;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

This does not work.  I also tried using the "unbind" option on the element and it also did not work.

Comment: Does your `bind` callback gets executed? Before or after the 3th party's bind method?

Comment: Before the 3rd party bind

Comment: Try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

> In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from
>   being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly
>   calling `event.stopPropagation()`. To simply prevent the event from
>   bubbling to ancestor elements but allow other event handlers to
>   execute on the same element, we can use `event.stopPropagation()`
>   instead.

So...

```
...
element.bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
});
...
```